# python Doc test or Unit test

Tags: python, testing, doctest

I have a bit trouble with python testing.
Below is a simple doctest in python. the information between """ has to be in the same file with the actual code.

I remembered somebody told me that I can put

```
>>> print( 2 + 2 )
4
```

Into a separate file if the output is too much or too long. When you do the doctest, open the file and compare.

I just can't remember how to do that now.

Can any body help me?

thanks

```
def _test():
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

Comment: You're right about the fact that `doctest` can be used to run tests that are written out in a test file, but more or less all of your actual examples are off in different ways. Check the [doctest documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) to see how test files work.

Comment: Thanks!!!
Test file!! that is the key word in search!!!

import doctest
doctest.testfile("example.txt")

Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this from a Google search as I had the same issue. I noticed there is an answer in the comments but the question is unanswered so adding a proper answer for future visitors.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html):

```
import doctest
doctest.testfile("example.txt")
```

This allows you to specify code in a test file and run a test using this file.